# Flutter using Android Studio - IDE not showing analysis errors or autocompleting imported package classes or methods

Tags: flutter, android-studio

As the title says, there are no analysis errors or code hints in the ide.

Autocomplete does not work either.  I've scoured the web for solutions to no success.

Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks for any insights,

-T

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue by creating a new Flutter Project